# How to autoexpand neosnippet with deoplete dropdown menu?

Tags: vim, neovim

Iam looking for an configuration (init.vim) to expand an neosnippet when selected with the deoplete plugin drop down menu.

What i've done so far:

1. Added all to vim-plug

   ```
   call plug#begin ('~/.local/share/nvim/plugged')
   Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim', { 'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins' }
   Plug 'Shougo/neosnippet.vim' | Plug 'Shougo/neosnippet-snippets'
   call plug#end ()
   ```
2. configured for autostart

   ```
   " Use deoplete.
   let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1
   " Use smartcase.
   let g:deoplete#enable_smart_case = 1
   " Set minimum syntax keyword length.
   let g:deoplete#sources#syntax#min_keyword_length = 2
   ```

This leads to this screen:[image: deoplug drop down selection]

Now I want to expand this snippet, when hitting `<Enter>` at the selection. Has anyone suggestion how to achiev that?

Thanks for your time and best regards,

Befedo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neosnippets doesn't expand automatically. You need to configure the key mappings. The project suggest the following to expand them using Ctr+k:

```
" Plugin key-mappings.
" Note: It must be "imap" and "smap".  It uses <Plug> mappings.
imap <C-k>     <Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)
smap <C-k>     <Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)
xmap <C-k>     <Plug>(neosnippet_expand_target)
```

If you want to expand them when using the popup menu use the following:

```
inoremap <silent><expr><CR> pumvisible() ? deoplete#mappings#close_popup()."\<Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)" : "\<CR>"
```

Comment: `deoplete#mappings#close_popup(` is not supported now, you must change this with `deoplete#close_popup(`.